# Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon, characters are not displayed properly sometimes

Tags: linux-mint

Linux Mint 17 with Cinnamon desktop.

Sometimes the characters will suddenly look like this without any warning, I have to login again to fix it.

Back to Mint 16, this machine never has this issue, only after I do a brand new Mint 17 install.

Does any one know what could cause this problem ?

Thanks

[image: characters not display properly sometimes]

Comment: it affects the titlebar and every other window, not only the terminal, right? What happens if you type `reset` in the terminal?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, it affects all the windows, not just terminal. So, `reset` command is probably not going to work, but I'll give it a try when it happens again.

Comment: did you ever find out a solution that does not involve changing windowmanagers? I have the same. It happens when I flip open my laptop and arch resumes from suspend. I use arch.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to **Preferences** -> **Fonts** and changing **Font Settings** to **Grayscale**. This immediately fixed the fonts in the terminal window but I had to restart Eclipse before the fonts displayed correctly there.